I try to model my mod file I get an error n:cs is undefined context: x[s, b, t] <= demand[s, >>> cs] <<< * z[s, b, t];
# SETS set B;                    # Candidate central kitchens set S;                    # Schools set CS;                    # Category School set T;                    # Time periods set K;                    # Set of commodities set N;                    # Set of nutrients set Y;                    # Set of food types set G {Y} within K;       # Set of food groups  # PARAMETERS param fixed_cost {B};                 # Fixed cost for each central kitchen param cost {S, B};                    # Distribution cost from central kitchen to schools param capacity {B};                   # Capacity of each central kitchen param demand {S, CS};                 # Demand per school param man_power {B};                  # Available workforce param handling_cost {B};              # Handling cost for each central kitchen param penalty_unmet;                  # Penalty for unmet demand param distance {S, B};                # Distance between each school and central kitchen param donation {T, B};                # Financial donations per central kitchen and time period param max_schools {B};                # Maximum number of schools each central kitchen can serve param trans_per_km;                   # Environmental transportation cost per km param nutrient_value {K, N};          # Nutritional value of each commodity per nutrient type param nutrient_requirement {N};       # Nutritional requirement per nutrient and time period param cost_commodity {K};             # Cost per commodity param total_nutrition;                # Total nutritional needs param disposal_cost {K};              # Disposal cost for unsold items  # VARIABLES var y {B} binary;                     # 1 if central kitchen b is opened var z {S, B, T} binary;               # 1 if school s is served by central kitchen b in period t var x {S, B, T} >= 0;                 # Quantity of food delivered to school s from central kitchen b var unmet_demand {S, T} >= 0;         # Unmet demand per school per time period var ratio_commodity {K, T} >= 0; var overshoot {N, S, CS} >= 0; var shortfall {N, S, CS} >= 0; var shortfall_indicator {N, T} binary;  # OBJECTIVE FUNCTIONS # 1. Minimize total cost minimize total_cost:     sum {s in S, b in B, t in T} cost[s, b] * z[s, b, t]       + sum {b in B} fixed_cost[b] * y[b]     + sum {s in S, b in B, t in T} handling_cost[b] * x[s, b, t]     + penalty_unmet * sum {s in S, t in T} unmet_demand[s, t];  # 2. Minimize environmental impact minimize environmental_cost:     trans_per_km * sum {s in S, b in B, t in T} distance[s, b] * z[s, b, t];  # 3. Maximize social benefit maximize social_benefit:     sum {s in S, b in B, t in T} z[s, b, t]     + sum {b in B} man_power[b] * y[b];  # 4. Maximize kilocalories provided maximize kilocalories:     sum {k in K, t in T} nutrient_value[k, "Energy"] * ratio_commodity[k, t];  # 5. Maximize nutrient value score maximize nutrient_value_score:     sum {n in N, s in S, cs in CS} (1 - shortfall[n, s, cs]) / total_nutrition * 100;  # CONSTRAINTS # 1. Capacity constraint per central kitchen and period subject to Capacity_Constraint {b in B, t in T}:     sum {s in S, cs in CS} demand[s, cs] * z[s, b, t] <= capacity[b] * y[b];  # 2. Limit number of schools served per central kitchen per period subject to Max_Schools_Constraint {b in B, t in T}:     sum {s in S} z[s, b, t] <= max_schools[b] * y[b];  # 3. Demand fulfillment constraint subject to Demand_Fulfillment {s in S, cs in CS, t in T}:     sum {b in B} x[s, b, t] + unmet_demand[s, t] >= demand[s, cs];  # 4. Delivery quantity constraint based on z subject to Food_Delivery {s in S, b in B, t in T}:     x[s, b, t] <= demand[s, cs] * z[s, b, t];      # 5. Nutrient optimization constraint subject to Food_Basket_Optimize {n in N, t in T}:     sum {k in K} nutrient_value[k, n] * ratio_commodity[k, t] >= nutrient_requirement[n];  # 6. Supplied nutrient constraint subject to Supplied_Nutrient {n in N, t in T}:     sum {k in K} nutrient_value[k, n] * ratio_commodity[k, t] = nutrient_requirement[n] * (1 - shortfall[n, s, cs] + overshoot[n, s, cs]);  # 7. Shortfall and overshoot constraints subject to Shortfall_Limit {n in N, t in T}:     shortfall[n, s, cs] <= shortfall_indicator[n, t];  subject to Overshoot_Limit {n in N, s in S, cs in CS}:     overshoot[n, s, cs] <= (1 - shortfall[n, s, cs]) * 10;  # 8. Ratio of food group constraints subject to Ratio_Group1 {t in T}:     sum {k in G["G1"]} ratio_commodity[k, t] = 0.33 * sum {k in K} ratio_commodity[k, t];  subject to Ratio_Group2 {t in T}:     sum {k in G["G2"]} ratio_commodity[k, t] = 0.17 * sum {k in K} ratio_commodity[k, t];  subject to Ratio_Group3 {t in T}:     sum {k in G["G3"]} ratio_commodity[k, t] = 0.33 * sum {k in K} ratio_commodity[k, t];  subject to Ratio_Group4 {t in T}:     sum {k in G["G4"]} ratio_commodity[k, t] = 0.17 * sum {k in K} ratio_commodity[k, t];          # Serve Only if Open Constraint subject to Serve_Only_If_Open{b in B, s in S}:     z[s, b, t] <= y[b];          # Allocation only when kitchen is open subject to Allocation_Constraint{b in B, s in S}:     x[s, b, t] <= demand[s, cs] * z[s, b, t ]; # SETS set B := FB1 FB2 FB3 FB4 FB5; set S :=      SDIT_NurulAmaliyah SDN12 SDIT_Nurul_ilmi SDN5 SMPN023      SDPJHI SMAPJHI SDN21 SDN06 SMPN8 SDN10 SDN20 SDN19      SDN11 SDN01 SMK_Azkiya SDN15 SDN02 SMPN19 SDN18      SMKN5 SDN03 SMP_DarunNajah SMK_DutaBangsa SDN09      SDN04 SDN17 SMPN13 SDN07 SMPIT_AlazharBS SDN08 SDN14; set CS:= SD SMP SMA; set T := 1; set K := Apple, Bananna, Beef, BeefLiver, Carrot, Cassava, CassavaLeaf, Chicken,              ChickenEgg, ChickenLiver, CoconutMilk, Corn, DuckEgg, FrenchBean, FreshMilk,             KidneyBean, LongBean, Manggo, Melon, MilkFish, Mungbean, Mushrooms,             Orange, Papaya, Pineapple, Potato, QuailEgg, Rambutan, Rice, Shrimp, SnakeFruit, Spinach,               Tomato, Watercress, WaterMelon, WaterSpinach, Yam, KembungFish, PatinFish, LeleFish, GabusFish, TongkolFish, TunaFish, TeriFish, Cauliflower, DragonFruit, Pears, SiamesePumpkin, Broccoli; set N := Water, Energy, Protein, Fat, Carbohydrate, Fibre, Calcium, Iron, Zinc, VitA, VitB1, VitB2,    VitB3, VitB6, VitB12, VitC, VitD, Folate; set Y := G1, G2, G3, G4; set G [G1] := Cassava, Potato, Rice, Yam; #merah - makanan pokok set G [G2] := Beef, BeefLiver, Chicken, ChickenEgg, ChickenLiver, DuckEgg, FreshMilk, MilkFish,             QuailEgg, Shrimp, KembungFish, PatinFish, LeleFish, GabusFish, TongkolFish, TunaFish, TeriFish; #biru - lauk pauk set G [G3] :=  Carrot, CassavaLeaf, CoconutMilk, Corn, FrenchBean, KidneyBean, LongBean, Mungbean, Mushrooms,           Spinach, Tomato, Watercress, WaterSpinach, Cauliflower, SiamesePumpkin, Broccoli; #kuning - sayuran dan buah - buahan set G [G4] := Apple, Bananna, Manggo, Melon, Orange, Papaya, Pineapple, Rambutan, SnakeFruit, DragonFruit, Pears, WaterMelon;  # PARAMETERS param fixed_cost :=     FB1 5000    FB2 6000    FB3 5500    FB4 5800    FB5 6200;  param cost : FB1  FB2  FB3  FB4  FB5 :=     SDIT_NurulAmaliyah  10   15   20   18   16     SDN12               12   18   25   22   14     SDIT_Nurul_ilmi     8    14   19   21   13     SDN5                14   11   22   17   18     SMPN023             16   13   24   19   17     SDPJHI              15   14   20   16   15     SMAPJHI             12   15   23   21   19     SDN21               19   14   20   22   15     SDN06               16   13   25   20   17     SMPN8               13   17   22   19   16     SDN10               18   15   24   21   19     SDN20               14   18   19   23   15     SDN19               12   14   22   16   18     SDN11               11   15   21   19   16     SDN01               14   12   23   17   15     SMK_Azkiya          17   13   20   18   16     SDN15               18   14   21   20   19     SDN02               16   15   22   19   17     SMPN19              13   17   24   20   18     SDN18               15   14   21   19   17     SMKN5               14   18   25   22   16     SDN03               12   15   23   21   19     SMP_DarunNajah      13   17   22   19   15     SMK_DutaBangsa      18   15   24   21   19     SDN09               14   13   22   17   18     SDN04               15   16   23   18   19     SDN17               18   14   22   19   17     SMPN13              16   13   24   20   18     SDN07               12   15   25   21   16     SMPIT_AlazharBS     15   17   23   20   19     SDN08               13   18   22   19   15     SDN14               16   14   25   22   18;  param capacity :=     FB1 200     FB2 250     FB3 240     FB4 230     FB5 260;  param demand :=     SDIT_NurulAmaliyah SD  100     SDN12              SD  80     SDIT_Nurul_ilmi    SD  70     SDN5               SD  60     SMPN023            SMP 90     SDPJHI             SD  50     SMAPJHI            SMA 75     SDN21              SD  85     SDN06              SD  65     SMPN8              SMP 55     SDN10              SD  80     SDN20              SD  70     SDN19              SD  60     SDN11              SD  75     SDN01              SD  85     SMK_Azkiya         SMA 90     SDN15              SD  80     SDN02              SD  60     SMPN19             SMP 75     SDN18              SD  85     SMKN5              SMA 95     SDN03              SD  70     SMP_DarunNajah     SMP 65     SMK_DutaBangsa     SMA 80     SDN09              SD  75     SDN04              SD  65     SDN17              SD  70     SMPN13             SMP 85     SDN07              SD  60     SMPIT_AlazharBS    SMP 90     SDN08              SD  70     SDN14              SD  80;  param man_power :=  FB1 10  FB2 12  FB3 11  FB4 13  FB5 14;       param handling_cost :=     FB1 5.0     FB2 4.5     FB3 6.0     FB4 4.5     FB5 5.0;    param max_schools :=     FB1 6     FB2 5     FB3 5     FB4 4     FB5 3;  param penalty_unmet := 1000;  param distance : FB1  FB2  FB3  FB4  FB5 :=     SDIT_NurulAmaliyah  3   5   7   6   8     SDN12               4   6   5   7   6     SDIT_Nurul_ilmi     2   6   8   5   4     SDN5                5   7   6   3   5     SMPN023             7   8   5   6   4     SDPJHI              6   5   4   7   3     SMAPJHI             5   6   8   4   7     SDN21               4   7   6   5   8     SDN06               3   6   7   8   4     SMPN8               7   5   6   4   8     SDN10               6   8   7   5   4     SDN20               5   6   8   4   7     SDN19               4   5   7   6   3     SDN11               6   7   5   8   4     SDN01               7   6   8   5   3     SMK_Azkiya          8   7   6   4   5     SDN15               7   6   5   8   4     SDN02               6   5   4   7   8     SMPN19              5   7   6   8   3     SDN18               4   6   7   5   8     SMKN5               8   5   6   7   4     SDN03               5   8   7   6   4     SMP_DarunNajah      7   6   5   8   4     SMK_DutaBangsa      6   7   8   5   3     SDN09               8   5   6   4   7     SDN04               7   8   5   6   4     SDN17               5   7   8   4   6     SMPN13              6   5   7   8   4     SDN07               7   6   5   4   8     SMPIT_AlazharBS     8   7   6   5   3     SDN08               6   8   7   5   4     SDN14               5   6   8   7   4;         param donation :=     [1, FB1] 1000  [1, FB2] 1200  [1, FB3] 1300  [1, FB4] 1100  [1, FB5] 900     [2, FB1] 1050  [2, FB2] 1150  [2, FB3] 1250  [2, FB4] 1200  [2, FB5] 950;       param trans_per_km := 2.5;      param nutrient_value :              Water   Energy  Protein Fat     Carbohydrate    Fibre   Calcium Iron    Zinc    VitA        VitB1   VitB2   VitB3   VitB6   VitB12  VitC    VitD    Folate:=                    Apple           84.1    68      0.3     0.4     14.9            2       6       0.3     0.02    4.79        0.04    0.01    0.1     0.041   0       5       0       5.46                    Bananna         72.9    112     1       0.8     24.3            1.9     20      0.2     0.2     6.08        0.05    0.11    0.1     0.367   0       9       0       23                  Beef            66      201     18.8    14      0               0       11      2.8     3.64    167.5       0.08    0.21    6.5     0.44    3.05    0       0       4.9                     BeefLiver       69.7    132     19.7    3.2     6               0       7       6.6     4       14153.5     0.26    0.96    5.4     1.08    59.3    31      1       290                     Carrot          89.9    43      1       0.6     7.9             1       45      1       0.2     477.96      0.04    0.04    1       0.138   0       18      0       19                  Cassava         61.4    156     1       0.3     36.8            0.9     77      1.1     0.1     0           0.06    0.12    0.5     0.088   0       31      0       27                  CassavaLeaf     84.4    68      6.2     1.1     7.1             2.4     166     1.3     2.6     455.58      0.04    0.1     1.8     0.34    0       103     0       0                   Chicken         55.9    298     18.2    25      0               0       14      1.5     1.5     246.625     0.08    0.16    8.1     0.35    0.31    0       0       4                   ChickenEgg      74.3    150     12.4    10.8    0.7             0       86      3       1.1     66.29       0.12    0.38    0.2     0.143   1.29    0       1       143                         ChickenLiver    53.4    261     27.4    16.1    1.6             0       118     15.8    0.5     6127.667    0.64    2.94    4.11    0.853   16.58   0       0       588                     CoconutMilk     54.9    348     4.2     34.3    5.6             0       14      1.9     1.1     0           0.02    0       0.4     0.05    0       2       0       0                       Corn            70.3    131     3.3     1.3     25.1            2.8     2       0.6     0.5     0           0.2     0.1     1.6     0.1     0       6       0       42                  DuckEgg         67.7    187     10.9    12.4    7.9             0       64      5.4     1.8     197.1       1.62    0.03    0.1     0.25    5.4     0       5       80                  FrenchBean      89.6    45      2.4     0.3     7.2             1.9     101     0.7     0.4     81          0.05    0.4     2.8     0.06    0       11      0       399                     FreshMilk       88.1    67      3.2     3.9     4.8             0       115     0.1     0.4     55          0       0.2     0.1     0.1     0.4     1       0       8                   KidneyBean      57.2    180     11      2.2     28              2.1     293     3.7     2.9     0.42        0.15    0.34    2.3     0.32    0       0       0       130                         LongBean        12.2    364     17.3    1.5     68.6            3.2     163     6.9     0.4     12          0.57    0.21    8.4     0.06    0       2       0       62                      Manggo          87.4    55      0.7     0.2     11.2            2.7     13      0.2     0.1     723.33      0.08    0.02    0.5     0.134   0       30      0       43                  Melon           83.8    36      0.6     0.4     7.2             0.5     0       0       0       0           0       0       10      0       0       0.1     0       21                  MilkFish        45.3    296     17.1    20.3    11.3            0       1422    1.9     0       22.67       0.14    0       0       0       0       69.09   0       16                  Mungbean        15.5    347     22.9    1.5     56.8            7.5     223     7.5     2.7     16.17       0.46    0.15    1.5     0.1     0       10      0       625                     Mushrooms       93.7    41      3.8     0.6     0.9             8.2     3       1.7     0.1     0           0.1     0.14    0.2     0.1     0       5       2       17                  Papaya          86.7    53      0.5     0.1     12.2            0.5     23      1.7     0.1     228         0.04    0.05    0.3     0.019   0       78      0       53.65                           Pineapple       88.9    46      0.6     0.3     9.9             0.6     22      0.9     0.1     4.58        0.02    0.05    0.2     0.11    0       22      0       18                  Potato          83.4    65      2.1     0.2     13.5            0.5     63      0.7     0.4     0           0.09    0.07    1.3     0.20    0       21      0       16.5                    QuailEgg        79.8    112     10.7    7       1.6             0       65      3.5     1.47    163.33      0.13    0.65    0.1     0.15    1.58    0       5       49                  Rambutan        80.5    79      0.9     0.1     18.1            1.1     16      0.5     0.1     0           0       0.06    0.4     0.1     0       58      0       8                   Rice            56.7    174     3       0.3     39.8            0       25      0.4     1.2     0           0.05    0.02    0.7     0.02    0       0       0       23                  Shrimp          75      86      21      0.2     0.1             0       136     8       1.3     18.33       0.01    0.39    3.6     0.1     1.19    0       3       3                   SnakeFruit      78      87      0.4     0.1     20.9            0.4     28      4.2     0       4           0.04    0.2     2.4     1       0       2       0       0                   Spinach         94.5    20      0.9     0.4     2.9             0.7     166     3.5     0.6     96          0.04    0.1     1       0.54    0       41      0       194                     Tomato          92.9    32      1.3     0.5     4.7             1.5     8       0.6     0.2     108.71      0.06    0.06    0.4     0.08    0       34      0       29                  Watercress      93.3    24      3.1     0.2     2.2             0.7     95      2.4     0.1     204         0.09    0.13    0.7     0.13    0       56      0       9                       WaterMelon      92.1    3.2     0.5     0.2     6.9             0.3     7       0.2     0.1     21.25       0.05    0.04    0.2     0.045   0       6       0       3                   WaterSpinach    91.0    40      3.4     0.7     3.9             2       67      2.3     0.5     345         0.07    0.36    2       0.10    0       17      0       57                  Yam             69.6    118     1.5     0.2     28              4.1     17      0.5     0.24    7           0.112   0.032   0.552   0.293   0       17.1    0       23                  KembungFish     73.5    111     19.04   0.9     4.8             0       68      7.3     0.6     0           0.03    0.2     7.3     0.05    12      0       16.1    1                   PatinFish       74.4    132     17      6.6     1.1             0       31      1.6     8       0           0.2     0.03    1.7     0.116   4.1     0       9       10                  LeleFish        80.36   95      16      2.82    0               0       14      0.25    0.25    70          0.21    0.072   1.907   0.116   4.1     0.7     12.5    10                  GabusFish       79.6    80      16.2    0.5     2.6             0       170     0.1     0.4     335         0.4     0.2     0.1     0       4.1     0       4.6     10                  TongkolFish     74.4    100     13.7    1.5     8               0       92      1.7     1.6     181         0.35    0.03    6.6     0.12    12      0       0       5.18                    TunaFish        62.3    132     28.2    1.29    0               0       37      1.6     1.05    18          0.24    0.25    8.65    1       0       0       82      5.18                    TeriFish        73.37   131     29      10      0               0       232     4.63    2.44    12          0.055   0.256   14.024  0.143   0.62    0       69      13                  Cauliflower     92.2    25      1.28    0.1     5.8             3.4     40      0.47    0.18    5           0.4     0.1     0.51    0.18    0       48.2    0       43                  DragonFruit     84      57      0.36    0.14    15.2            3.1     9       0.18    0.1     1           0.012   0.026   0.16    0.029   0       4.3     0       4.04                    Pears           84.1    63      0.38    0.16    15.1            3.1     8       0.17    0.07    1           0.012   0.026   0.16    0.029   0       4.3     0       4.04                    SiamesePumpkin  94.24   19      0.8     0.1     4.5             1.7     17      0.3     0.74    0           0.025   0.029   0.47    0.076   0       7.7     0       93                  Broccoli        89.3    34      2.82    0.37    6.64            2.6     47      0.73    0.41    31          0.071   0.12    0.64    0.18    0       89.2    0       65;     param nutrient_requirement :                SD      SMP     SMA:=                           Water           1850    2100    2300                            Energy          2000    2400    2650                            Protein         55      70      75                          Fat             65      80      85                          Carbohydrate    300     350     400                             Fibre           28      34      700                             Calcium         1200    1200    1200                            Iron            8       11      11                          Zinc            8       11      11                          VitA            600     600     700                             VitB1           1.1     1.2     1.2                             VitB2           1.3     1.3     1.3                             VitB3           12      16      16                          VitB12          3.5     4       4                           VitC            50      75      90                          VitD            15      15      15                          Folate          400     400     400;                             param cost_commodity :=                    Apple           4000                            Beef            15000               BeefLiver       10000               Carrot          3000                Cassava         2000                CassavaLeaf     1500                ChickenEgg      2000                ChickenLiver    5000                CoconutMilk     3000                Corn            8000                DuckEgg         3000                FrenchBean      5000                    FreshMilk       10000               KidneyBean      5000                LongBean        3000                Manggo          3500                Melon           1500                MilkFish        5000                Mungbean        4000                Mushrooms       5000                Orange          7000                Papaya          3000                Pineapple       2000                Potato          3500                QuailEgg        5000                Rambutan        5000                Rice            1200                Shrimp          10000               SnakeFruit      2000                Spinach         4000                Tomato          1000                Watercress      8000                WaterMelon      1500                WaterSpinach    1000                Yam             1200                KembungFish     3500                PatinFish       3000                LeleFish        3000                GabusFish       6000                TongkolFish     3000                TunaFish        5000                TeriFish        2000                    Cauliflower     1500                DragonFruit     2000                    Pears           2500                SiamesePumpkin  600                 Broccoli        3000;                                                        param total_nutrition := 18; param disposal_cost := 20;    ampl: include cost.run;  cost.mod, line 79 (offset 3713):   cs is undefined context:  x[s, b, t] <= demand[s,  >>> cs] <<<  * z[s, b, t];  cost.mod, line 87 (offset 4115):   cs is undefined context:  (1 - shortfall[n, s,  >>> cs] <<<  + overshoot[n, s, cs]);  cost.mod, line 87 (offset 4115):    s is undefined context:  (1 - shortfall[n, s,  >>> cs] <<<  + overshoot[n, s, cs]);  cost.mod, line 87 (offset 4137):     cs is undefined context:  (1 - shortfall[n, s, cs] + overshoot[n, s,  >>> cs] <<< );  cost.mod, line 87 (offset 4137):    s is undefined context:  (1 - shortfall[n, s, cs] + overshoot[n, s,  >>> cs] <<< );  cost.mod, line 91 (offset 4254):     cs is undefined context:  shortfall[n, s,  >>> cs] <<<  <= shortfall_indicator[n, t];  cost.mod, line 91 (offset 4254):  s is undefined context:  shortfall[n, s,  >>> cs] <<<  <= shortfall_indicator[n, t];  cost.mod, line 111 (offset 5060):  t is undefined context:  z[s, b,  >>> t] <<<  <= y[b];      cost.mod, line 115 (offset 5186):    t is undefined context:  x[s, b,  >>> t] <<<  <= demand[s, cs] * z[s, b, t ];     cost.mod, line 115 (offset 5202):   cs is undefined context:  x[s, b, t] <= demand[s,  >>> cs] <<<  * z[s, b, t ];
# Reset and load files
reset;
# Load model and data files
model cost.mod;
data cost.dat;
# Set solver and multi-objective options
option solver gurobi;
option solver_options 'multiobj=1';
# Set objective priorities
suffix objpriority IN;
let total_cost.objpriority := 3;
let environmental_cost.objpriority := 4;
let social_benefit.objpriority := 5;
let kilocalories.objpriority := 2;
let nutrient_value_score.objpriority := 1;
# Solve the problem
solve;
# Display key decision variables and objective values
display y, z, x;
display total_cost, environmental_cost, social_benefit;
display unmet_demand;
display kilocalories;
display shortfall[SD, *];
display shortfall[SMP, *];
display shortfall[SMA, *];
